# How to discourage scraping on a Drupal website?

Tags: drupal-7, web-scraping

I have a Drupal website that has a ton of data on it. However, people can quite easily scrape the site, due to the fact that Drupal class and IDs are pretty consistent.

1. Is there any way to "scramble" the code to make it harder to use something like [PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape the site?
2. Are there other techniques that could make scraping the site a little harder?
3. Am I fighting a lost cause?

*I am not sure if "scraping" is the official term, but I am referring to the process by which people write a script that "crawls" a website and parses sections of it in order to extract data and store it in their own database.*

Comment: What's your specific concern about organisations scraping your website? Don't want Google indexing your site?

Comment: I am scared the competition can grab a ton of data in one go, that we have had to sit and put together over a long period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think that it is quite easy to crawl a website where all contents are public, no matter if the IDs are sequential or not. You should take into account that if a human can read your Drupal site, a script also does.

Depending on your site's nature if you don't want your content to be indexed by others, you should consider setting registered-user access. Otherwise, I think you are fighting a lost cause.

Comment: Well, for example, if the ID is "description" on page 1, and on page two the title has the ID "description", it would make things a bit harder for a scraper. Also, I am sure there are ways to limit how fast certain IPs access your website?

Comment: I think it does not matter how complicate titles are, if a human is able to reach a content just navigating through your menus and links, or using google, your contents will be found. It has been demonstrated that securing a software just hiding info that is guessable is not a good measure. However, you could have a look at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/ban

Answer (score 2):

1. First I'd recommend you to google over [`web scraping anti-scrape`](https://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=web%20scraping%20anti-scrape&oq=web%20scraping%20anti-scrape&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.8391j0j7). There you'll find some tools for fighting web scrapig.
2. As for the Drupal there should be some anti-scrape plugins avail (google over).
3. You might be interesting my [categorized layout of anti-scrape techniques](http://scraping.pro/my-site-is-being-scraped-how-can-i-prevent-being-scraped/#more-7517) answer. It's for techy as well as non-tech users.